# In fiber wave guide we only consider transverse (TM,TE,EH) modes of laser. Why not we consider londitudenal modes?

Tags: electromagnetism, fiber-optics, laser-cavity

Laser beam guiding through fiber.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Electromagnetic waves are transverse (except maybe for a charge density wave).